# Mac OS X very often crashing with Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I am using Eclipse ADT on Mac OS X, when working with the Android Emulator, my Mac crashes very often and requests to turn off the power and restart.

I am using:

Mac OS X 10.7.4

Eclipse Indigo

ADT 18.0.0

All the software are updated to the latest version wherever appropriate.

Are anyone working with the same conditions successfully or facing similar issue? Please advice me.

Comment: I am running Indigo, OSX 10.6.8 and when i boot up the emulator it has never crashed. I would recommend the purchase of an Android Device, if you dont have one already, it makes life much easier. If you do have one then turn on debugging mode and connect it to your Mac, the AVD should recognize it and you can tests all your builds on their. Its a much faster process.

Comment: A device is fine, but I need the emulator specifically for screencasts and testing various screen sizes.  This appears to be a serious bug for a lot of people: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19099

Comment: I've the same problem here. Also android 2.3.3 emulator doesn't detect portrait and landscape changes

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: This did not work for me...I got the same crash after a few hours.  **I installed Eclipse 4.2** now that it's stable and so far it and the emulator are working like champs.

---

I'm trying this now...will see if it makes a difference over the next day or two. (Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2, Mac OSX 10.7.4)

From [Issue 19099](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19099):

> In eclipse.ini I used the following values:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

*The original entry in the issue report has "256m" on the same line as the --launcher.XXMaxPermSize, but that 1) didn't seem right and 2) caused Eclipse to crash for me. Moving to a new line (like it was before this change) is okay so far.

Comment: I solved this problem by installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in a different partition in my Mac machine, and using Eclipse and emulator with Ubuntu. No problems at all! Ubuntu is faster than Mac as well!

Comment: Cool - I'll have to try that out!